# How to create a custom Exception Handler for a list with custom messages?

Tags: java, unit-testing, exception

I need to create a integer list which accepts strings as values and meet these requirements:

The added values must be string representations of numbers. The list should throw a custom exception with a custom message in case:
 * the added value is null or empty
 * the added value is not the string representation of a number
 * the index we try to read from the list is out of bounds

I also have some unit test which checks whether I handled the exceptions properly.

This is the CustomException class :

```
public class CustomException extends Exception {

    public CustomException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }


    public CustomException() {
    }


    public CustomException expect(NumberFormatException e) {
        return new CustomException("Not a number");
    }

    public CustomException expect(NullPointerException e) {
        return new CustomException("Null");
    }

    public CustomException expect(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        return new CustomException("Index out of bounds");
    }
}
```

And here are the Unit TESTS :

```
public class MyListTest {

    private List<String> list;

    private Class<CustomException> exceptionType = CustomException.class;

    private String[] initData = {"12", "23", "34", "45"};

    @Rule
    public ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        this.list = new StringList();
    }

    @Test
    public void testAddValuesToTheList() {
        initData();
        assertEquals(initData.length, list.size());
        for (String data : initData) {
            assertTrue(list.contains(data));
        }
    }

    private void initData() {
        for (String numberAsString : initData) {
            list.add(numberAsString);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testAddNonIntegerValue() {
        exception.expect(exceptionType);
        exception.expectMessage("Invalid number.");
        list.add("Hey, I'm not an integer.");
    }

    @Test
    public void testAddNonNullValue() {
        exception.expect(exceptionType);
        exception.expectMessage("Null");
        list.add(null);
    }

    @Test
    public void testIndexOutOfBounds() {
        initData();
        exception.expect(exceptionType);
        exception.expectMessage("Index out of bounds.");
        list.get(initData.length);
    }
}
```

So my question is : How to use the Custom Exception class in order to check for the requirements from above for my List ?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: It is not clear what the answer is. You just said your requirements...

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void add(Object element) {
        if (element == null) {
            try {
                throw new CustomException("Null");
            } catch (CustomException e) {
                System.err.println("Null");
            }
        } else {
            list.add(Integer.valueOf((String) element));    
        } //how to handle NUMBER FORMAT EXCEPTION WITH MY CUSTOM EXCEPTIONS

    }
```

above is your code and every single method in your file is doing very simmilar mistake , you are `throwing out the exception` from within the `try catch block` custom exception will be `thrown` bt it will be `handled` at the `same time` if you are planning on `throwing` out the `exception` do it like this 
change your other `methods` too.

```
public void add(Object element) throws CustomException {
            if (element == null) {
                throw new CustomException("Null");
             } else {
                list.add(Integer.valueOf((String) element));    
            } //how to handle NUMBER FORMAT EXCEPTION WITH MY CUSTOM EXCEPTIONS

        }
```

Comment: this was marked as corrrect yesterday and it is not marked as the correct  answer  today why what happened.

Comment: seriously you had to ,remove the last question and post your new question over it.
people already gave the answers for the last question is now reffering to something very unrelated even can downvoted by other users , thnx